# android:translationY property hides the bottom border of Edittext

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I"m using Textinput layouout to get user information and with EditText inside. I'm using background as shape with borders at four side.

I was facing a problem that hint text used to cut off by border of Edittext so searched for solution and declaring 
                        **`android:translationY="10dp"`**
in xml did the trick. But now the bottom border is invisible and only top, right, left border are visible after declaring that attribute.

How can I fix this.

Here is my xml layout.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MobileText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipChildren="false">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/availaible_location"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                    android:hint="Satdobato, Thimi, Balkhu..."
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:inputType="textShortMessage|textMultiLine"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:translationY="10dp"

                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and my background edit_txt.xml  layout is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#949494"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change layout_height of TextInputLayout to "112dp". Your moving EditText 10dp in Y direction. TextInputLayout has wrap_content so Editext is hidden inside TextInputLayout.

android:layout_height="112dp"

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in your Edit Text this:

```
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
```

You need to do padding and delete de Translation, you have to play with the value.
If the problem persists, try to do:

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

I hope It will help you!